# Importing flask.ext raises ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, flask

When I try to use Flask extensions, my application is raising `ModuleNotFound` errors on lines like `from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy` or `from flask.exthook import ExtDeprecationWarning`. I have Flask and the extension installed. Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 23):

Something in your code, or in code you're using, is trying to import `flask.ext` or `flask.exthook`, which no longer exists in Flask 1.0. They were completely removed after being visibly deprecated for at least a year, and implicitly deprecated for many years before that. Anything that still depends on it must be upgraded.

Any use of `from flask.ext import ...` should be replaced with a direct import of the extension. For example `flask.ext.sqlalchemy` becomes `flask_sqlalchemy`.

The only reason to import `from flask.exthook import ExtDeprecationWarning` is to silence the previous deprecation warnings. Since it no longer exists, there is no warning to silence, and that code can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in `/bin/superset` and it was only for warnings, so I muted it like this :

```
#from flask.exthook import ExtDeprecationWarning
from superset.cli import create_app

#warnings.simplefilter('ignore', ExtDeprecationWarning)
```

see the commented lines. additionally, installing sqlalchemy==1.2.18 helped for errors that followed (this line may not be relevant so just an FYI)!

Answer (score 0):

This may help people who have come across this thread because they have had a `No module named 'flask.ext' error`.

From the beginning, I had set up the `from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy`, so I didn't understand what the problem was.
What finally worked was to upgrade the sql alchemy with `pip3 install --upgrade Flask-SQLAlchemy`.