# How can I create sql dump for a flask application

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I would like to export or import sql db from a flask application. After searching I found the following package which is supposed to do the job.

https://pypi.org/project/Flask-AlchemyDumps/

But it seems it doesn't work with flask now .

Thats what I have tried

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask.ext.alchemydumps import AlchemyDumps, AlchemyDumpsCommand
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from commands import create_tables
from config import Config

db = SQLAlchemy()

app = Flask(__name__)

manager = Manager(app)

# init Alchemy Dumps
alchemydumps = AlchemyDumps(app, db)
manager.add_command('alchemydumps', AlchemyDumpsCommand)
```

I get this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask.ext'`

Is there any alternatives available?

Comment: I think the `flask` part isn't interesting to the problem.  I think you need to ask how to do an sql dump from a python application.  `flask` just provides an HTTP interface to do that.  The first question you'd need to answer is "what type of SQL?"  Are you using `sqlite` `mariadb` `postgresql`?

Comment: Please post the code from the file that gives you that error.

Comment: @Stewart sqlite

Comment: @Bert  code added.

Comment: `flask.ext` is deprecated, you may have learned that cold from a very old tutorial. See this answer for more details - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261135/importing-flask-ext-raises-modulenotfounderror