# import flask_store in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am having probably a very stupid problem for the people who knows how to do...
But I can't find the way to import flask_store in my python code file in VSCode.
I tried pretty much all the differents way i found in internet.
It keeps saying

> Import "flask_store" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports)

I checked where it is installed, it is in the same folder as flask, which works..

VSCode is using Python 3.9.1.
and this is what I have in my terminal:

> Name: Flask-Store
> Version: 0.0.4.3
> Summary: Provides Django-Storages like file storage backends for Flask Applications.
> Home-page: http://flask-store.soon.build
> Author: SOON_
> Author-email: dorks@thisissoon.com
> License: MIT
> Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages
> Requires: Flask, shortuuid

If i write

> from flask_store import Store

I keep having the error message.
How should I do?? I didn't write one line of code in 2 hours just because of that...:-)
Can someone help me??
Sorry, I am a very begginer!

Comment: After checking that you've installed the module in current used python environment, open Command Palette and choose **Developer: reload window**, which won't throw error when importing `flask_store`.

Comment: @MollyWang Thank you! I will try that

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the import statement:

From [Flask-Store](https://github.com/thisissoon/Flask-Store)

```
from flask.ext.store import Store
```

Comment: I found that in another topic, but doesn't work as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261135/importing-flask-ext-raises-modulenotfounderror

Answer (score 0):

In between, I found out that I can't anymore run Flask..
So i uninstall flask. And i read in the terminal that:

> flask-store 0.0.4.3 requires Flask==0.10.1, but you have flask 2.0.1 which is incompatible.

So maybe it comes from that, simply... so I uninstall both, and pip install flask only.

Is there a way to make it work? Or is there something similar that I could use?
I just basically need to check in Python if there is a key in the localStorage and compare its value to know which db.txt to show, or create an empty one if needed. (This is an exercice to use Flask, Python, Javascript and the localStorage, for the course and project I must build)

Comment: So, the error is caused by incompatible flask version. please specify version to install it: `pip install flask==0.10.1`. Try and see if the error goes away.